# Collection List having more than one type of user defined objects?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, interface

I have a static list:

```
public static List<IMachines>mList =new List<IMachines>();
```

The list intakes two different types of objects(machines) in it:

```
IMachines machine = new AC();
IMachines machine = new Generator();
```

If after adding items to the list, I want to search for a particular machine by its name property then after using the foreach loop for traversal if that item is found in list ... how am I supposed to know if the item is of `AC` type or `Generator` type?

Comment: "how am I supposed to know if the item is of AC type or Generator type?" You're not. By referring to the object via the `IMachines` interface you're saying that only things specified by that interface is what you care about. There are ways around it, but the correct answer is usually fixing the design issue that requires you to do it.

Comment: There are different ways to do it. `is` `as` operators and also the one described in my answer. But Telastyn is right here. You should fix the design issue and have everything that is needed exposed through the interface.

Comment: should i use class reference variables instead of interface ? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "is" operator.

```
List<IMachines> list = new List<IMachines>();
list.Add(new AC());
list.Add(new Generator());
foreach(IMachines o in list)
{
  if (o is Ingredient)
  {
    //do sth
  }
  else if (o is Drink)
  {
    //do sth
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`is` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

> Checks if an object is compatible with a given type

For example:

```
if(item is AC)
{
  // it is AC
}
```

Comment: Note that if you subsequently want to treat `item` as an `AC` then you could use the `as` operator and check for null, at which point you have your typed `AC` ready to use.

Answer (score 3):

```
    interface IVehicle {

    }

    class Car : IVehicle
    {

    }

    class Bicycle : IVehicle
    {

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var v1 = new Car();
        var v2 = new Bicycle();

        var list = new List<IVehicle>();
        list.Add(v1);
        list.Add(v2);

        foreach (var v in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v.GetType());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `OfType()` method to return only items that are of the specified type:

```
IEnumerable<Generator> generators = mList.OfType<Generator>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `is` and `as` operators.

```
        List<IMachines> mList =new List<IMachines>();
        IMachines machine = mList.Where(x => x.Name == "MachineName").FirstOrDefault();

        if (machine != null)
        {
            if (machine is Generator)
            {
                Generator generator = machine as Generator;
                //do something with generator
            }
            else if (machine is AC)
            {
                AC ac = machine as AC;
                //do something with ac
            }
            else
            {
                //do you other kinds? if no, this is never going to happen
                throw new Exception("Unsupported machine type!!!");
            }

        }
```

Comment: It does not make sense to use as operator in combination with is. If you decide to use `is` then direct casting to the matching type will not throw an exception.

The best solution here is using `as` operator and checking for null.

Comment: If `machine is Generator`, machine **can't** be `null` because `null` objects don't have types. So the surrounding `if` is obsolete.

Comment: @fero, No, <code>if (machine != null)</code> is to protect from the null that the preceding call to FirstOrDefault could return that I use after calling Where. So machine could be null if the list if empty, or doesn't contain any machine with the name provided in the Where. Again, the if is not redundant.

Comment: @MZN No, you didn't get me right: The checks for `machine is Generator` or `machine is AC` return always `false` if machine is `null`. So you don't need an additional check for `null`. (And yes, I'm totally aware that `FirstOrDefault` may return `null`.) The only difference is that, with your `if`, you won't get an exception if the `FirstOrDefault` returns no object. BTW: You can combine the `Where` and the `FirstOrDefault` because `FirstOrDefault` has an overload which accepts a predicate just like `Where`.

Comment: @fero, Aha, now I get you! It didn't occur to me to use is operator with a null value. Also, yes it would've been better just to use FirstOrDefault. I just discovered that overload yesterday. Thanks much for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do different operations based on types, you can use `GroupBy` `type`.

By doing this, you can get sub list corresponding to each derived type.

Following is code snippet

```
    void Main()
    {
        List<IMachines> mList = new List<IMachines>();

        mList.Add(new AC());
        mList.Add(new Generator());
        mList.Add(new AC());
        mList.Add(new Generator());
        mList.Add(new Generator());
        mList.Add(new Generator());

        var differentIMachines = mList.GroupBy(t=>t.GetType());
        foreach(var grouping in differentIMachines)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Type - {0}, Count - {1}", grouping.Key, grouping.Count());

                foreach(var item in grouping)
                {
                //iterate each item for particular type here
                }
        }

    }

    interface IMachines {   }

    class AC : IMachines {}

    class Generator : IMachines {}
```